# Audio overlapping in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio

I've done a lot of reading and research in trying to come up with a solution to my problem and can't seem to make my code work the way I want, or the way it should. What I want to do is be able to have different buttons play different, short sounds, without overlapping each other if I decide to click another sound button before another sound button's audio is finished. I've successfully got to the point where they play their designated sound using `SystemSoundID`, but they still overlap when I click on multiple `buttons`.

Below is a sample of my code:

Interface file:

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
}

-(IBAction)Sound:(id)sender;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@implementation ViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)Sound:(id)sender 
{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Sound" ofType:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioPlayer* theAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL  fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];
    [theAudio play];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

@end
```

I would appreciate the help more than you know, as I've spent quite some time trying to get it to work the way it should. If you have any questions for me please let me know! Thank you very much.

-Michael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the understanding that when you play an AudioSystemSound that it will play until completion. This method of playing Audio isn't a highly functional one and only really supposed to be used for simple "clicks" and "dings" etc. For a more comprehensive audio suite of features perhaps you could look at using the AVFoundation library with AVAudioPlayer where you can call "stop" to cease playing the called sound.

https://developer.apple.com/av-foundation/

Edited addition to the above answer:

In your .h file make sure you include;

```
@import AVFoundation;
```

and then create an AV player with;

```
AVAudioPlayer *playAudio
```

In your .m file add this block of code below in your method that needs to play the sound. Of course adjust the song/audiofile name and format appropriately;

```
NSString *backgroundMusic = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                             pathForResource:@"insertSongNameHere" ofType:@"mp3"];

playAudio = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:insertSongNameHere] error:NULL];
playAudio.numberOfLoops = -1;
[playAudio play];
```

Note: Number of loops being -1 means repeat forever. You can of course make that whatever number you like though. I hope that all helps, if not let me know and I'll see what I can do to assist!

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback Frankeex. I've edited my code above using AVAudioPlayer, but for some reason the sound will no longer play and I have no clue as to why.

Comment: @Michael - I edited my answer above with more specific help. Hope that gets you going.

Comment: With some slight tweaks this worked perfectly! Thanks again Frankeex, I really do appreciate the help.